# Pyqt5 QAction triggered event error in Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qaction

I developed a GUI application with python and pyqt5 in Ubuntu 16.04. There is an QActionBar in application that have some clickable items. All of functionalities in Ubuntu works perfect. As I want to export executable file for MS Windows, I was forces to migrate to Windows.

The problem is running same code gives me an error:

```
TypeError: connect() failed between triggered(bool) and newProject()
```

And this is part of my codes:

```
self.actionNewProject = QtWidgets.QAction(GoodProject)
...
self.actionNewProject.triggered.connect(self.newProject)
...
@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def newProject(self):
    print('foo')
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line "pyqtSlot()" will solve this issue